# C++ issue with function in constructor

Tags: c++

I came accross quite odd problem which I can't really solve on my own, it considers simple C++ program.

I know that I can and probably should use setFunction instead of list which will initialize variables, but I'm doing this just to get the sense how it's all working.

Let me introduce you to my code, this one is fully compileable (the difference between this one and the other has been marked):

```
#include <iostream> 
#include <string> 

using namespace std; 

class SimpleClass
{
private: 
  string name; 
public: 
  SimpleClass(string z): name(z)
  {
    string getName(z); // ***HERE WE HAVE getName() function with return type string

  }

  string getName()
  {
    return name; 
  }
}; 

int main(void)
{
   SimpleClass object("Pussycat"); 
   cout << object.getName() << endl; 
}
```

This one isn't working, since **I did not specify return type of function getName()**, which used to return value name:

```
#include <iostream> 
#include <string> 

using namespace std; 

class SimpleClass
{
private: 
  string name; 
public: 
  SimpleClass(string z): name(z)
  {
     getName(z); // *** WITHOUT STRING TYPE BEFORE FUNCTION NAME
  }

  string getName()
  {
    return name; 
  }
}; 

int main(void)
{
   SimpleClass object("Pussycat"); 
   cout << object.getName() << endl; 
}
```

Any ideas why the second one isn't not working ?

Comment: `string getName(z);` is a `string` called `getName`, initialized to be the same as `z`.

Comment: getName(z) is a call to a function called getName that takes a string as an argument.  You don't have a function with that signature.   Your getName() function does not have any arguments.  A better question though, is what are you intending to do with the getName lines that are inside the constructors?

Comment: For the sake of brevity (I know, a lost cause) we shall assume "This one isn't working" means *This does not compile successfully*.

Answer (score 3):

In this block of code,

```
SimpleClass(string z): name(z)
{
  string getName(z); // ***HERE WE HAVE getName() function with return type string
}
```

You have a function local variable named `getName` of type `string`. It is constructed using the `z` and is discarded. It is not related to the class member function `getName`.

In this block of code,

```
SimpleClass(string z): name(z)
{
   getName(z); // *** WITHOUT STRING TYPE BEFORE FUNCTION NAME
}
```

You are calling the member function `getName` with `z` as the argument, which fails to compile because `getName()` does not take an argument.

Answer (score 0):

First, `getName()` does not take any parameters. You should not call it that way in the constructor.

Secondly, why do you even call get name? You already initialize name by using its constructor `name(z)`.

Answer (score 0):

In the first case within the body of the constructor you define local object with name `getName` and initialize it with string z. After exiting the constructor this local object will be destroyed

```
  SimpleClass(string z): name(z)
  {
    string getName(z); // ***HERE WE HAVE getName() function with return type string

  }
```

For that would be more clear the code above is equivalent to

```
  SimpleClass(string z): name(z)
  {
    string getName = z;

  }
```

In the second case you call member function `getName` and set argument for it. However the function is declared with no having parameters. See your declarations

```
  SimpleClass(string z): name(z)
  {
     getName(z); // *** WITHOUT STRING TYPE BEFORE FUNCTION NAME
  }

  string getName()
  {
    return name; 
  }
```

If you want that the code would be compiled you have to write at least like

```
  SimpleClass(string z): name(z)
  {
     getName();
  }

  string getName()
  {
    return name; 
  }
```